# Reading Nested JSON via Spark SQL - [AnalysisException] cannot resolve Column

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a JSON data like this:

```
{  
   "parent":[  
      {  
         "prop1":1.0,
         "prop2":"C",
         "children":[  
            {  
               "child_prop1":[  
                  "3026"
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

After reading data from Spark I get following schema:

```scala
val df = spark.read.json("test.json")
```

```
df.printSchema
root
 |-- parent: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- children: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- child_prop1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- prop1: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- prop2: string (nullable = true)
```

Now, I want to select `child_prop1` from `df`. But when I try to select it I get `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException`. Something like this:

```
df.select("parent.children.child_prop1")
```

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`parent`.`children`['child_prop1']' due to data type mismatch: argument 2 requires integral type, however, ''child_prop1'' is of string type.;;
'Project [parent#60.children[child_prop1] AS child_prop1#63]
+- Relation[parent#60] json

  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:82)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:74)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:310)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:310)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:309)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:307)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:307)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5.apply(TreeNode.scala:331)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:188)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildren(TreeNode.scala:329)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:307)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressionUp$1(QueryPlan.scala:282)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$2(QueryPlan.scala:292)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$2$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:296)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$2(QueryPlan.scala:296)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$7.apply(QueryPlan.scala:301)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:188)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressionsUp(QueryPlan.scala:301)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:74)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:67)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:128)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.checkAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:67)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.checkAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:57)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:63)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$withPlan(Dataset.scala:2822)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.select(Dataset.scala:1121)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.select(Dataset.scala:1139)
  ... 48 elided
```

Although, when I select only `children` from `df` it works fine.

```scala
df.select("parent.children").show(false)
```

```
+------------------------------------+
|children                            |
+------------------------------------+
|[WrappedArray([WrappedArray(3026)])]|
+------------------------------------+
```

I cannot understand why it is giving exception even though the column is present in dataframe.

Any help is appreciated !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Json is a valid json which and I think you don't need to change your input data.

Use explode to get the data as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode

val data = spark.read.json("src/test/java/data.json")
val child = data.select(explode(data("parent.children"))).toDF("children")

child.select(explode(child("children.child_prop1"))).toDF("child_prop1").show()
```

If you can change the input data you can follow @ramesh suggestions

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the schema `child_prop1` is inside `nested array` of root array `parent`. So we need to be able to define the `position` of the `child_prop1` and thats what the error is suggesting you to define.
Converting your `json` format should do the trick. 
Changing the `json` to

```
{"parent":{"prop1":1.0,"prop2":"C","children":{"child_prop1":["3026"]}}}
```

and applying the

```
df.select("parent.children.child_prop1").show(false)
```

will give output as

```
+-----------+
|child_prop1|
+-----------+
|[3026]     |
+-----------+
```

And 
Changing the `json` to

```
{"parent":{"prop1":1.0,"prop2":"C","children":[{"child_prop1":["3026"]}]}}
```

and applying the

```
df.select("parent.children.child_prop1").show(false)
```

will result

```
+--------------------+
|child_prop1         |
+--------------------+
|[WrappedArray(3026)]|
+--------------------+
```

I hope the answer helps